# c++ input till end of input signalled through keyboard

Tags: c++, logic, user-input, xterm, g++-4.7

I want to write a C++ (C, if it provides easy solution to my problem) program where one may input until he chooses to signal *end of input* by pressing such combination of buttons as Ctrl+D. I have two questions regarding this.

1. Which key-combination(s) is/are used to signal the *end of input* in Xterm? (Ctrl+C or Z didn't work)
2. What should be the logical code in my `while()` loop to process accordingly, when one presses the key combination as answered in 1?

   ```
   map<int,string>info;
   string name;
   int age;
   cin>>name;
   while( ????????? ){   //Input till EOF , missing logic
       cin>>age;
       info.insert( pair<int,string>(age,name) );
       cin>>name;
   }
   //sorted o/p in reverse order
   map<int,string> :: iterator i;
   for(i=info.end(); i !=info.begin(); i--)
       cout<<(*i).second<<endl;
   cout<<(*i).second<<endl;
   ```

   }

The program proceeds upon receiving the end of input signal from terminal.

I use `gcc/g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3`.

Answer (score 0):

The while condition should be something like:

```
while(the_key_combination_pressed_in_the_last_loop!=what_combination_will_exit_while)
{
  cin>>age;
  if(age!=what_combination_will_exit_while)
  {
      info.insert( pair<int,string>(age,name) );
      cin>>name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `istream_iterator`

The default constructor of which wait for EOF

i.e `Ctrl+Z` or `F6+ENTER` on windows

`Ctrl+D` on linux

I'd use a proxy class to insert into map on the fly, something like as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<class Pair>
class info_reader // Proxy class, for overloaded << operator
{
public:
        typedef Pair pair_type;

        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, info_reader& p)
        {
              return is >> p.m_p.first >> p.m_p.second;
        }

        pair_type const& to_pair() const
        {
                return m_p; //Access the data member
        }
private:
        pair_type m_p;                
};


int main()
{
    typedef std::map<int, std::string> info_map;

    info_map info;
    typedef info_reader<std::pair<int, std::string> > info_p;

       // I used transform to directly read from std::cin and put into map
        std::transform(
            std::istream_iterator<info_p>(std::cin),
            std::istream_iterator<info_p>(),
            std::inserter(info, info.end()),
            std::mem_fun_ref(&info_p::to_pair) //Inserter function
                );

//Display map
for(info_map::iterator x=info.begin();x!=info.end();x++)
   std::cout<<x->first<< " "<<x->second<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: inserting into map is not that big of a concern for me. I want a c++ logic smthng like `while(cin>>name){...}` which stops processing on input as soon as _Key-Combination_  is pressed. But obviously that won't work.So suggest me some other method.

Comment: @KunalKrishna the above code will work with `Ctrl+D` (linux) or `Ctrl+Z`
Do you want any other key combination ?

Comment: @POW I got answer for first part wrt key combination. But I am having hard time implementing it. The problem is using a same construct I have to do whatever if it is string and **exit** if its that key combination.